# Android ScrollView ignores its border (Screenshots attached)

Tags: react-native

Trying to set border to `ScrollView` component. On iOS it works just fine, but not on Android:

```
 scrollView: {   
   borderColor: '#000000',
   borderStyle: 'solid',
   borderWidth: (1),
 }
```

Nice black border on iOS:

[image]

No black border on Android:

[image]

Try here: https://rnplay.org/apps/cJbAjg

Comment: Can you post the core code sample within the body of the question? It is possible the link will go out of date, and this can help when searching as well.

Answer (score 5):

Can't really explain why, but one of the fixes is the following:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({   
  container: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 1,   
  }, 
  scrollView: {         
    height: 40,   
  },   
  item: {       
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    borderRadius: (5),
    padding: 5,
    margin: 5,   
  } 
});
```

I've tested this on an android device  using rn 0.26.0

Comment: Thanks, it is nice workaround, but not exactly what i need

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the prop **styles** use **contentContainerStyle**

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}></ScrollView>
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Can you link to the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 1):

```
<View
style={{overflow : "hidden" , borderRadius : 20}}
>
<ScrollView>
{/*Your other view*/}
</ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.